# Validating form fields in Blazor Serverside manually with errors

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I need to choose when to validate certain model fields on a Blazor component, specifically on submission.
So, I need to figure out how to manually validate model values so that I can use the built in error handlers to handle displaying the errors.

Ex:

```
If you choose RadioValue: type A  
    only validate Textfield 1,  
    do not validate Textfield 2, Textfield 3  
If you choose RadioValue: type B  
    validate Textfield 1, Textfield 2, and Textfield 3  
If you choose RadioValue: type C  
    validate no fields
```

Any fields not being validated are being set behind the scenes on submission.

Extra notes:

- Using custom Radio input components, since MS doesn't provide them.
  They do however have an example of one in their [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/forms-validation?view=aspnetcore-3.1#work-with-radio-buttons), so mine is
  essentially a clone of that.
- I've tried an event listener with OnFieldsChanged to get the fields
  but I have no way of
     A) Validating a specific model
     B) Ensuring an error message is associated with that model, and works with the ValidationMessage component.
- It seems I can only check if eveything is valid using the EditContext.Validate() but I can't choose what to validate.
- Also if I could validate with and without attributes, that would
  makes things easier.

MS' version of validation on a separate server, I'd prefer the same app, yet they don't explain how they validate the values and return an error.

```
<EditForm EditContext="@_editContext" OnSubmit="@HandleSubmit">

    ...

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</EditForm>

@code {
    private Starship _starship = new Starship();
    private EditContext _editContext;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        _editContext = new EditContext(_starship);
    }

    private async Task HandleSubmit()
    {
        var isValid = _editContext.Validate() && 
            await ServerValidate(_editContext);

        if (isValid)
        {
            ...
        }
        else
        {
            ...
        }
    }

    private async Task<bool> ServerValidate(EditContext editContext)
    {
        var serverChecksValid = ...

        return serverChecksValid;
    }
}
```

I'll get an example of my code soon to provide more context, but I'm hoping that maybe it can be solved without it.

Comment: Did you consider using [FluentValidation](https://blog.stevensanderson.com/2019/09/04/blazor-fluentvalidation/) ?

Comment: I had seen some things about it in a few places but I hadn't considered it. However, the link you provided seems to showcase more or less what I need. I'll give it a go and I'll see if it does what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think  FluentValidation can be of much help here. FluentValidation may be more flexible, but the issue is with the EditContext.Validate method that does not support partial validation of  models. This is a very painful subject much discussed in Github, especially when one wants to implement multi-step wizard. Consider creating a couple of models to implement this, hoping that in the future good solutions may be provided by the Blazor team or Blazor community.

Comment: That is unfortunate, because that is the exact basis of the project I'm currently working on. I've opted to use a large model, and then separated smaller models for each razor component. The smaller models on submission get validated and added to the larger model, where at the end of the "wizard", the large model gets posted to an API. So far however FluentValidation seems to be working for what I need from the example that @aguafrommars provided me. Hopefully something is built in/supported from MS in the future for those use cases.

Comment: This is basically the boat I'm in.  Have they come up with a solution for this scenario?